# Is it possible to build an app for iPhone 5 screen size with the former SDK (iOS5)?

Tags: iphone, ios6

The latest SDK (Xcode 4.5) doesn't support armv6 and I need to support it right now, so I don't want to upgrade Xcode. Can I support iPhone 5 screen size and make an app in non letterbox mode on iPhone 5 from the previous Xcode (4.3.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] Comment by Brad Larson, change it all : Apple is now explicitly rejecting applications submitted with the iOS 5.x SDK and iPhone 5 default images, saying "Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."

You can build an app that is compatible with iPhone 5 screen size by adding the 640x1136 Default-568h@2x.png in your resources (if the splash screen defined in your Info.plist is Default.png).
Xcode below 4.5 will let you test on iOS6 devices which is a new for Apple as when iOS5 arrived, all previous version of Xcode where not compatible with iOS5 (impossible to test on iOS5 devices).
So, YES you can develop for iOS6 and iPhone5 screen size from Xcode 4.4 or 4.3.

Comment: re "Xcode below 4.5 will not let you test on a iOS6.0 device"
- before iOS 6 was actually released, this was the case. once iOS 6 was actually released tho, my older XCode (4.3) started working w/ my iOS 6 device.

Comment: Note that Apple is now explicitly rejecting applications submitted with the iOS 5.x SDK and iPhone 5 default images, saying "Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."

Comment: My experience is that it's not the iOS 5.x SDK, but the iOS Deployment Target that is causing this problem. We built using iOS 6 SDK, but set the deployment target to iOS5, including the 568 png in the plist and we got rejected with the "launch image size" message. We will try to remove it from the plist, but not from the ipa, see how that goes.